# Frequentists tests to check for normality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, qq-plot, lilliefors-test

Let $X_1,...,X_n\sim X$ be $n$ i.i.d. random variables. I want to to test if they follow a normal distribution, in other words, check if their distribution belongs to the Gaussian family.

These are the tests I'm considering:

- Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
- Kolmogorov-Lilliefors test

With these two tests I can statistically test the hypothesis that my data was sampled from a normal distribution. Further tests for univariate normality I've found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test#Frequentist_tests). I would also like to check for normality visually (with QQ-Plots and histograms), which raises the question,

Is a normal QQ-test a valid way to test for normality?

This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278330/durbin-watson-test-and-how-to-do-normal-q-q-plot-and-normal-p-p-plot) refers to the normal QQ-test, so perhaps someone could confirm if it's legit to use.

And is QQ-Plot the same as a normal QQ-test or am I confusing concepts here?

Comment: Please explain what a "normal QQ-test" is.

Comment: To be honest @whuber I'm not completely sure myself, hence my question. I'm only familiar with QQ-Plots and normal QQ-Plots, and encountered this "normal QQ-test" for the first time today (in a lecture exercise). Researching online doesn't yield much information about this test, although there is one [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281876492_New_Graphical_Methods_and_Test_Statistics_for_Testing_Composite_Normality) published 2015 which mentions the "Power of Q-Q test for normality".

Comment: We don't have the information from the class you got it from; you have context that we don't. It might be a reference to either a Shapiro-Francia or a Ryan-Joiner test, but it might just be talking about the version of Q-Q plots that have the bounds drawn on combined with a rejection rule "reject normality if the QQ plot goes outside the bounds drawn on the plot".

Comment: It looks like the paper you link is taking some version of that last approach.

Comment: I'm on the same boat as you @Glen_b . In class I've only studied QQ-Plots and as I said I encountered this "normal QQ-test" for the very first time as of yesterday; never saw it before neither in theory nor in practice. Does this "version of that last approach" refer to your comment "reject normality if the QQ plot goes outside the bounds drawn on the plot"? Or what do you refer to with last approach.

Comment: yes, that was the last of the three ways I mentioned that could be called a "Q-Q test of normality"

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Glen_b it's very much appreciated. I posted another question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596574/critical-value-for-a-2-sided-walds-test), do you mind sharing your thoughts there too? Cheers!